# GWT changing package structure, unable to find gwt.xml

Tags: java, gwt, jetty, package

I've developed whole project under GWT in Eclipse Juno. After developing it and testing it (it worked fine) I decided to change a little bit the root package structure.

From

```
sk.jakub
```

to

```
sk.jakub.app
```

Nothing serious. I changed all the referencies in my .xml files. But I still obtain following error:

```
Loading modules
   sk.jakub.Editor1
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'sk/jakub/Editor1.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

The problem evidently is that GWT tries to find the Editor1.gwt.xml under old package structure. The package structure wasn't updated.

I thought that I forgot to update the Entry Point Module settings but they are fine. So I don't understand why is this happening.

Any suggestions how to resolve this problem ?

Thank you very much for your answers :)

UPDATE:
here is my deployment descriptor(seems fine to me):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<!-- Context params -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/*-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Listeners -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring4gwt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring4gwt</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/editor1/app/componentService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Editor1.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: check your deployment descriptor (`web.xml`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse, got to `run, run configurations, select your project, select the arguments tab.`

In the program arguments window make sure you have an updated entry.  I think you'll need:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher sk.jakub.app.Editor1
```

Comment: thanks there was a problem that i had sk.jakub.Editor1 and then sk.jakub.app.Editor1. And it took only the first path and not the second... but I did not realize that it added a new path instead of editing the existing one :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your GWT compiler settings. You have to specify the GWT module(s) including the package. When refactoring the package structure you have to correct these settings.

When compiling in Eclipse the GWT "Compile" dialog lists the "Entry point modules". Check if the module "Editor1" is listed and has the correct package structure.

When starting as a Web Application in Development Mode you have to check the tabs "GWT" and "Arguments" if your module is listed correctly.

Same applies for ant builds.

Comment: thanks - the problem was localized in Arguments tab inside RunConfigurations :) it was not filled correctly